# Combining two ng-repeats in a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want do use two different ng-repeat loops in a table to kind of group different obejcts with each other but don't know really how to do it.

My code right now:

```
...
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person1 in Array1">
        <td>{{ person1.address }}</td>
        <td>{{ person1.city}}</td>
        <td>{{ person1.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person2 in Array2">
        <td>{{partner2.address }}</td>
        <td>{{partner2.city}}</td>
        <td>{{partner2.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

The result/table i'm aiming for:

```
person1[1].address   |    person1[1].city    | person1[1].email
---------------------------------------------------------------
person2[1].address   |    person2[1].city    | person2[1].email
---------------------------------------------------------------
person1[2].address   |    person1[2].city    | person1[2].email
---------------------------------------------------------------
person2[2].address   |    person2[2].city    | person2[2].email
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

That is, i'd like to the ng-repeat to out put person1[1] and person2[1] before putting out person1[2].

Is the solution to add an outer array, containing my two current arrays or are there any better solution?

best regards

Comment: Any reason not to combine the arrays into a new array?

Comment: I agree with Zack.  You can interleave the two arrays to produce one combined array and then use ng-repeat on the combined array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you could ensure that your array had no null values and were the same length, you could use this technique:

Create a new array initialized to the length of the two other arrays and iterate on this to get `$index`. 
Put your ng-repeat on the body ( you can have multiple `body` elements in a table).

You'd get something like this:

```
var counterArray = new Array(array1.length);
<tbody ng-repeat="item in counterArray">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ Array1[$index].address }}</td>
        <td>{{ Array1[$index].city}}</td>
        <td>{{ Array1[$index].email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td>{{ Array2[$index].address }}</td>
        <td>{{ Array2[$index].city}}</td>
        <td>{{ Array2[$index].email}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It might be safer to use a getter function on those arrays also:

```
getData(index,array,value)
```

Where you can prevent any null errors from occurring.

Comment: that is awesome! solved it through a ng-repeat over one of the current arrays without creating a new one